# How many posts have I edited?

Tags: support

When I'm at the review page, the posts I've edited are 59:

[image]

But when I go to Users > Editors > All, I have edited 86 posts.

[image]

Which one is correct?

As a matter of fact, the same happens on Musical Practice. There is like a ~30 posts difference between the review page and the users page.

Comment: You can get a detailed answer on Data Stackechange site. It has queries for editor badges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full details are given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/172958), under Copy Editor, the gold-level equivalent.

> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to community wiki posts do count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits do count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

The difference is most likely tag-only edits. If you only change tags, that counts as an "edit" in the editors list but not for the badges.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but I think the first is the number of *posts* you've edited, and the second is the number of *times* you've edited posts. The ~30-post difference represents times you've made more than one edit to the same post.